# Prevent browser from scrolling to select element when focusing

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I prevent browser from scrolling when focusing? Here's my code:

```css
select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 55em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<select multiple>
  <option selected="">Lorem</option>
  <option selected="">ipsum</option>
  <option selected="">dolor</option>
  <option selected="">sit</option>
  <option selected="">amet</option>
  <option selected="">Lorem</option>
  <option selected="">ipsum</option>
  <option selected="">dolor</option>
  <option selected="">sit</option>
  <option selected="">amet</option>
</select>
```

Try choosing an option or two.

Comment: Are you not wanting to use javascript at all?

Comment: It's just that I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

As your requirement, I'd suggest you use `position: fixed` for the temporary body block (removed immediately with `setTimeout`)

With this solution, `onfocus` is good enough (no need to have `onblur`)

```js
function blockScroller(event) {
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
  body.classList.add("scroller-blocker")

  setTimeout(() => {
    body.classList.remove("scroller-blocker")
  })
}
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 55em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scroller-blocker {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<select multiple onfocus="blockScroller(event)">
  <option selected="">Lorem</option>
  <option selected="">ipsum</option>
  <option selected="">dolor</option>
  <option selected="">sit</option>
  <option selected="">amet</option>
  <option selected="">Lorem</option>
  <option selected="">ipsum</option>
  <option selected="">dolor</option>
  <option selected="">sit</option>
  <option selected="">amet</option>
</select>
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

You can block the scroller with `overflow: hidden` on your element `body`

`onfocus` is triggered whenever an user focuses on a element

`onblur` is triggered whenever an user clicks outside of a focused element

Note that for mobile devices, you need to remove `touchmove` event for completely blocking screen moving

```js
const touchMoveEvent = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}

function blockScroller() {
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
  body.classList.add("scroller-blocker")

  //avoid touch move event on mobile
  body.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMoveEvent)
}

function unblockScroller() {
  const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
  body.classList.remove("scroller-blocker")

  //put the default behaviour of touch move event back 
  body.removeEventListener('touchmove', touchMoveEvent)
}
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 55em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scroller-blocker {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<select multiple onfocus="blockScroller()" onblur="unblockScroller()">
  <option selected="">Lorem</option>
  <option selected="">ipsum</option>
  <option selected="">dolor</option>
  <option selected="">sit</option>
  <option selected="">amet</option>
  <option selected="">Lorem</option>
  <option selected="">ipsum</option>
  <option selected="">dolor</option>
  <option selected="">sit</option>
  <option selected="">amet</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not really what I want. I still got pulled down when choosing an option.

Comment: I updated my code for the sake of your requirement. You can verify it again :D @AdHominem

Comment: Nothing change.